# Can Auto Gather Stats approach should replace traditional gather stats approach in data warehouse?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse

I am wondering about Gather Statistics strategies for a Data warehouse.

As per my own research- now oracle 19c provides automatic gather statistics feature.

Is that useful for data warehousing environment as well or that is more relevant for OLTP?
As per my research traditional approach is creating a task to gather stats on my ETL batch load run itself.

Do you think that auto gather stats may be more beneficial than traditional approach? If yes then why?

Thanks,

Rajneesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a very good whitepaper on this and that answers my queries. Sharing here with hope it may be useful for others in community:

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/bi-datawarehousing/twp-bp-for-stats-gather-19c-5324205.pdf

Thanks,
Rajneesh